# Excel VBA how to loop a redundant conditions

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Hello to the community, 
I'm trying to simplify my code with a looping for a copy paste. 
The below code succeed on 1) refresh one cell from one product and 2) copy the refreshed table onto a specific slide number.

I need to replicate the procedure x7 times - instead to have a long code, I thought I could loop the conditions with the following.
 - refresh the product (from 8 to 1), calculate
 - then copy paste the excel table to its slide
The combination is like this.
Product (Sheets) goes to Presentation (Slides)
Product 8 goes to Slide 9
Product 7 goes to Slide 8 etc..

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportToPPT()

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim Sel As Range
    Dim source As Range`

    Workbooks("WWDWT.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Graph Data").Select
    Range("E4").Value = "8"
    Application.Calculate

    Set Sel = Selection
    Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("D1")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("D1:AE40").Copy

    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(9)
    ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap

End Sub
```

How could I loop the `Range("E4").Value = "8"` to change to 7,6,5,4... and allocate each of them to the `Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(9)` that follow as Slide(8),7,6,5 etc..
Thanks all in advance for the help

Comment: Use a `For` loop. Add `Dim i as Long`, then `For i = 8 to 1 Step -1`, then `Range("E4").Value = i`, then `Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i+1)`, finally a `Next i`.

Comment: @BigBen post as an answer... that's awful to read in a comment.  was mid post on that, but wasn't going to duplicate you

Comment: @Cyril haha I was mid-post too and then didn't want to comment on the use of `Selection` and `ActiveWorkbook`, well I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `For` loop, like this:

```
Sub ExportToPPT()
    ...
    Dim i as Long

    For i = 8 to 1 Step - 1
        Workbooks("WWDWT.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Graph Data").Select
        Range("E4").Value = i
        Application.Calculate

        Set Sel = Selection
        Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("D1")
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("D1:AE40").Copy

        Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i + 1)
        ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
    Next i

End Sub
```

But note that using `Activate` and `Select` usually isn't necessary. You can simplify

```
Workbooks("WWDWT.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Graph Data").Select
Range("E4").Value = i
```

to

```
Workbooks("WWDWT.xlsm").Sheets("Graph Data").Range("E4").Value = i
```

And you never use `Sel` from `Set Sel = Selection` so maybe you can get rid of that (and `source` too?)

And I'm guessing that `ActiveWorkbook` is actually the `Workbooks("WDWT.xlsm")` too...

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - this is indeed correct, active workbook is WDWT file - I know select is not a good usage in VBA, but thought I could use it only once. let me try your proposal